# Prove that all light bulbs can't light off

Tags: combinatorics

We are given a table of dimensions $2010\times2012$ where every cell has one light bulb. At the beginning, the number of "on" light bulbs is greater than $2009\times2011$. If in any part of table dimensions $2\times2$ there are three "off" light bulbs, then the fourth light bulb is also turned off. Otherwise nothing happens. Prove that at least one light bulb is turned on at the end.

I first thought splitting the table into $2\times2$ parts but I'm not sure how to do so. After that I found that $2010\times2012-(2009\times2011+1)=2011^2-1-2010^2=4020$ which is the maximum of light bulbs turned off. I have no idea where to go from this. Any help/hints are appreciated.

Comment: "At the beginning the number of turned light bulbs...." What's a turned light bulb? Is that turned on, or turned off?

Comment: @GerryMyerson turned on

Comment: @Chinny84 I guess it could be,but this is a problem from 2nd grade high school and we do induction in 4th grade,though if you know how to solve it with induction would be nice to see it :P

Comment: Prove that in the initial configuration there is a row or column with every light on, then prove that all the lights in that row or column stay on.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't think there is. You only need to turn off 2012 lights to turn one off from every row and column, and at the beginning we have 4021 bulbs off.

Comment: @Ben, good point. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @kingw3 fair point. I will retract my comment. :)

Comment: (To correct my previous comment: we have 4020 bulbs off, as the question now mentions. I misinterpreted $>$ as $\ge$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the question, the maximum number of bulbs off at first is twice the number of rows, and two less the number of columns.

Our worst case scenario here looks like this, where $0$ is a bulb that's off and $1$ is on:

\begin{bmatrix}
0  & 0     & 1      & 1  & 1 & \ldots       & 1     & 1  \\
1  & 0     & 0      & 1  & 1 & \ddots       & 1     & 1 \\
1  & 1     & 0      & 0  & 1   & \ddots          &  \ddots     & 1 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots    \\
1  &  1   & \ddots   & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\
1 & 1    & \ldots  & \ldots  & 1       & 0     & 0      & 1
\end{bmatrix}

In this configuration, we have two diagonals of off bulbs side by side. Every $1$ touching the diagonal (except for the $1$s in the last column, mind you!) can be "attacked" by the three $0$s that share a $2 \times 2$ square with it, and then its neighbors can be attacked, and so on. This still leaves the last column completely on because there's no way to attack it.

Note that if there is a break in the diagonals of $0$s in the "worst case scenario" above, then all the bulbs won't turn off, because we will have a configuration like this within our $2010 \times 2012$ matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
0  & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Observe here that no way to attack the $1$s in the $2 \times 2$ square in the middle, nor the $1$s behind them in squares extending away from the center.